# Why does Task.Run() in windows service OnStart() cause the service to refuse to stop?

Tags: c#, windows-services, task-parallel-library, topshelf

## I'm not sure why this service is refusing to stop.

I ran into this when trying to correct a `TimeoutException` thrown when starting the service. Using:

```cs
public void OnStart()
{
    _startTask = Task.Run(DoWork, _cancelTokenSource.Token);
}

private void DoWork(){ [listen for things and operate on them] }

public void OnStop()
{
    _cancelTokenSource.Cancel();
    _startTask.Wait();
}
```

I understand that implementing a simple timer will solve this, but that's not the point of my question. Why does the use of `Task.Run(() => action, _tokenSource.Token)` resolve the `TimeoutException` but causes the service to not respond to control messages?

### The issue Observed

After installing and starting the service (it's TopShelf BTW), I'm unable to stop the service by conventional methods.

#### First Attempt:

[image]

#### All Subsequent Attempts:

[image]

## Edit: Still no joy

Here is my attempt after following the [provided example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads#listening-by-registering-a-callback).

```cs
public void Start()
{
    var token = _cancelTokenSource.Token;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Setup(token), token);
}

public void Stop()
        {
            _cancelTokenSource.Cancel();
            //TearDown(); <-- original implementation of stop
        }

private void Setup(CancellationToken token)
        {
            _mailman.SendServiceStatusNotification(_buildMode, "Started");
            ... create some needed objects

            token.Register(TearDown);

            InitializeInboxWatcherProcess(...);

        }

private void TearDown()
        {
            _inboxWatcher.Terminate();
            _mailman.SendServiceStatusNotification(_buildMode, "Stopped");
        }

private void InitializeInboxWatcherProcess(...)
        {
            // pre create and initiate stuff
            _inboxWatcher = new LocalFileSystemWatcherWrapper(...);
            _inboxWatcher.Initiate();
        }
```

---

```cs
public class LocalFileSystemWatcherWrapper : IFileSystemWatcherWrapper
    {
        // do FileSystemWatcher setup and control stuff
    }
```

Comment: Cancellation is **cooperative**. Have you written code within `DoWork` that checks for whether cancellation has been requested?

Comment: Besides what @Damien_The_Unbeliever said, why are you waiting for a cancelled task to finish?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I saw it in an example that didn't really fit my issue, so it is out of ignorance. @Damien_The_Unbeliever, baring the `.Wait()` which I understand now is not needed, if my `DoWork` checks for the cancellation request is my code in working order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely because you either don't have a cancellation method, or there are subprocesses inside of `DoWork()` that are still running when you call `Cancel()`.  As @Damien_The_Unbeliever said cancellation is a cooperative task.

When you call `_cancelTokenSource.Cancel()` if you haven't registered a callback function all that happens is that a boolean value `isCancellationRequested` is set to true, the `DoWork()` method is then responsible for seeing this and stopping its execution on its own.  There is a flaw here, though, as you can probably tell, that if you have a time consuming loop running in the `DoWork()` task when `Cancel()` is called, that loop will have to finish an iteration before it can check the value of `isCancellationRequested` which can lead to hanging.

The way around this is to insert cancellation callback functions INTO the `DoWork()` method, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads#listening-by-registering-a-callback) and then register them to the token, so that when you call the `Cancel()` method, ALL of the tasks running in the background are stopped without having to wait for them.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I can add a code example if you need one, but I felt MSDN's example was sufficient

Comment: Maybe I'm still doing something wrong b/c I'm still not getting the service to stop. I'll try to update my question. The live version of the `DoWork` method is using [System.IO.FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.7.2) if that helps.

Comment: My issue had something to do with the scope of the variables I was using. If I register the callback on the token to a method accessing instance fields for the watcher(s) before those fields have value, the cancellation doesn't disable the watcher event handlers. If I give those fields have value before registering the `TearDown` method it works fine. Do you know where I would find some documentation on why this happens?

Comment: I'll take a look into it when I get home later